# Identity Server 4 on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm learning Identity Server4, just a simple example. one server one client.
When i run the server on Kestrel, everything is fine. 
but if i deploy the server to IIS, when i try to visit a Action with [Authorize] attribute from client, it throws an exception.

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://myip:5555/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://myip:5555/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

even if i can access to http://myip:5555/.well-known/openid-configuration normally.

I searched and tried many solutions but none of them works.

Thanks anyone in advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a certificate check if is trusted certificate on your IIS machine.
[How to trust the IIS Express Self-Signed Certificate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/)

Comment: @Elan.Cao are you using a certificate IdentityServer4Auth.pfx, on your local machine?